# How to save entire Scrollable canvas as Png

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, png

I have a Canvas class that implements VirtualizingPanel and IScrollInfo. This class is contained inside a ScrollViewer. How can I save the contents of the entire Canvas class only as Png?

I know how to save as Png, problem is what is the easiest way to grab only the particular control. When the control is out of view, it gets clipped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to do this with a virtualizing panel as its whole goal in life is to keep the number of children it contains to an absolute minimum.

What you might want to do is create a non-virtualizing version in code and use that for your png generation.